# TableView trazer data, do banco de dados mysql

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho uma Table View, que recebe os dados de uma tabela no meu Banco, até então consegui trazer os dados normalmente, mas a data está vindo diferente da registrada no banco, sempre trás de 1 dia anterior.

Por exemplo:

No banco está: 2018-09-06
Na minha TableView retorna: 2018-09-05

O que pode estar ocasionando esse erro?

Alguns dados de como estou declarando a data:

```
import java.util.Date;

private Date datavisita;

public Date getDatavisita() {
return datavisita;
}

public void setDatavisita(Date datavisita) {
this.datavisita = datavisita;
}

//metodo para filtrar a data:

v.setDatavisita(rs.getDate(“datavisita”));

//declaração da coluna data
@FXML
TableColumn<VW_Visitas_Sonho, Date> colData;

// configurar as colunas de acordo com o objeto VW_Visitas_Sonho

colData.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(“datavisita”));
```

Comment: Quando você faz um print das datas elas estão corretas?

Comment: No banco estão corretas, quando mostro na minha tableview vem sempre com 1 dia a menos, uma outra curiosidade, tenho 1 filtro por data, quando filtro pela data de hoje por exemplo, 13/09/2018, ele me traz a data correspondente que é 12/09/2018.

Comment: Acredito que esteja ocorrendo um problema entre java.sql.Date (a que vem do banco) e o java.util.Date, não é necessariamente um problema no TableView porque o mesmo só exibe a informação guardada.

Comment: O que você me indica a fazer para resolver esse problema? estou sem saber o que fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que é um problema na hora de converter as datas. Vou sugerir que use a nova API de datas do Java 8 [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)/[LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). O java.sql.Date vem com um método chamado [toLocalDate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) que você pode utilizar.

```
private LocalDate datavisita;

public Date getDatavisita() {
    return datavisita;
}

public void setDatavisita(LocalDate datavisita) {
    this.datavisita = datavisita;
}
```

Aqui vamos utilizar o método toLocalDate().

```
System.out.println(rs.getDate(“datavisita”).toLocalDate()); // Verifique antes
v.setDatavisita(rs.getDate(“datavisita”).toLocalDate());
```

Mude a declaração do seu table Column:

```
TableColumn<VW_Visitas_Sonho, LocalDate> colData;

// [...] A configuração está correta
colDate = new TableColumn<>("Data");
colData.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(“datavisita”));
```

Se o problema persistir por algum motivo você pode adicionar um dia facilmente ao LocalDate utilizando o método plusDays();

```
v.setDatavisita(rs.getDate(“datavisita”).toLocalDate().plusDays(1));
```

Se tiver problemas pra formatar a data veja este artigo: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/

Obs.: Verifique também se não há problemas de fuso horário, nesse caso utilize ZonedLocalDate e cuidado com null.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tive que usar o plusDays, com ele funcionou corretamente, obrigado pela atenção, me ajudou muito.